# What is the role of receiver.html in the chromecast flow? Is it required?

Tags: chromecast

I have been looking over a recent example app for chromecast and found that they did not include an example receiver.html? https://github.com/googlecast/cast-ios-demo-player

I was under the impression that the receiver.html was required, and was to be specified in the code, much like the original example at https://github.com/googlecast/cast-ios-sample

Can someone help clarify in this new example what is going on?  I havent been able to identify where it specified in the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Receiver at https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-sample/tree/master/receiver for all the demos. (Android, iOS, and Chrome)

Comment: Can you kindly point me in the project where the address of the receiver is specified? https://github.com/googlecast/cast-ios-demo-player

Comment: Line 27, your APP ID HERE,  of the Receiver, and line 24 of CastViewController.m

Comment: Ok, bare with me here, line 24 is: static NSString *kReceiverAppName = @"[YOUR_APP_NAME]";  Are you saying that the receiver URL should be put into "YOUR_APP_NAME"?  In the other example (line 40 GCKAppDelegate.m) you actually set the receiver url.  Is that no longer needed when using app ID's (which are synonymous with "app_name"?)

Comment: your AppID goes in both places. (Receiver and line 40).  That will launch the URL you registered with. You can then pass in what you need to get to your content. either in that line, or in a separate launch method.  It should be some from of URI, though most developers will use a URL.